# Powershell script to automate IE Office 365 login. The click() function does not register the "Keep me signed in" page even though it clicks past it

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, click

I made a copy of my code here.

https://gist.github.com/nick050183/b9c6ecbc753f2eaba2373b5c24ac5c81

The issue happens at line 196.

What I'm trying to accomplish:
We are mapping Office 365 Sharepoint drives to our users machines. In order to do that you need to have the sharepoint site added to the IE Trusted zone AND you need to log in to sharepoint with the "keep me signed in" option activated.

The trouble we run into is that IE even when told to "keep me signed in" sporadically logs out. Which means we need a script to log in to Sharepoint every time a user signs in to the machine.

Everything in the script works except for the Click() function on the Keep me signed in page.

The click() sort of works. It logs in to sharepoint. But it doesn't actually register the keep me signed in portion. The reason I know this is because if I pause the script at that very step and manually click on the "Yes" button. It works perfectly. But when I click on it with the powershell script it never works.

Gives me this error

```
NET : System error 224 has occurred.
At C:\Users\abishop\Desktop\IElogin.ps1:272 char:1
+ NET USE $Drive[$i] $Location[$i] /PERSISTENT:YES
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System error 224 has occurred.:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Access Denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first add the web site to your trusted             sites list, browse to the web site, and select the option to login automatically.
```

The code on the Office 365 page is as follows

```
<div data-bind="css: { 'inline-block': isPrimaryButtonVisible }" class="inline-block"> <!-- type="submit" is needed in-addition to 'type' in primaryButtonAttributes observable to support IE8 --> <input type="submit" id="idSIButton9" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-bind="
        attr: primaryButtonAttributes,
        value: primaryButtonText() || str['CT_PWD_STR_SignIn_Button_Next'],
        hasFocus: focusOnPrimaryButton,
        click: primaryButton_onClick,
        enable: isPrimaryButtonEnabled,
        visible: isPrimaryButtonVisible,
        preventTabbing: primaryButtonPreventTabbing" aria-describedby="KmsiDescription" value="Yes">     </div>
<!-- type="submit" is needed in-addition to 'type' in primaryButtonAttributes observable to support IE8 -->
<input type="submit" id="idSIButton9" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-bind="
        attr: primaryButtonAttributes,
        value: primaryButtonText() || str['CT_PWD_STR_SignIn_Button_Next'],
        hasFocus: focusOnPrimaryButton,
        click: primaryButton_onClick,
        enable: isPrimaryButtonEnabled,
        visible: isPrimaryButtonVisible,
        preventTabbing: primaryButtonPreventTabbing" aria-describedby="KmsiDescription" value="Yes">
```

I've tried a dozen different ways to select that item. With different tag approaches. Tried to focus() it and tried to submit() it. Nothing seems to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your error again... Seems to occur on line 260 with `NET USE $Drive[$i] $Location[$i] /PERSISTENT:YES` not line 196. The error message is `Access Denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first add the web site to your trusted sites list, browse to the web site, and select the option to login automatically.` See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/troubleshoot-mapped-network-drives microsoft has a page documenting this issue that you can find by copying and pasting the error into your web browser.

Comment: I'm in favor of NekoMusume's reply. The error message has prompted the solution. You could refer to [the steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/troubleshoot-mapped-network-drives#troubleshoot-mapped-network-drive-error-messages) in the official doc to solve the issue. Besides, I find [a similar thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/764668/i-cant-map-a-network-drive-to-sharepoint) and you could refer to the accepted answer.

Comment: That error only happens because the KMSI option is not going through.

If you pause the script at step 5 before it ever clicks that "Yes" button where its asking you if you want to stay signed in. Manually click it with the mouse. Then run the NET USE function it will work. So technically yes the actual error is happening at line 260. But it is line 196 that is creating that behaviour.

You need 3 things for the drive map to work:
1) Add the site to IE trusted sites (done through Regedit in the script)
2) Log in to Sharepoint through IE 
3) Set the "Keep me signed in" option to yes.

Comment: I probably should have explained that last part a little bit better.

I broke down the steps that IE has to go through to log in into 5 different steps. One step for each window.

The very last step before you log in asks you if you would like to Stay logged in. The other name for this is "Keep me signed in". You absolutely have to click "Yes" for the drive map to work. Not only that, it appears that the click() doesn't actually do everything a normal mouse click would do in that instance.

Comment: Have you added breakpoints around the click function to debug? Does the click function `primaryButton_onClick` be triggered when you use powershell script to click the "Yes" button in IE? I think it can tell if the button has been clicked successfully.

Comment: Did you ever got this to work?